# Если я в качестве параметра укажу обьект типа Object смогу ли я использовать любой обьект в качестве параметра?

Tags: java

```
protected Reader(Object lock) {
    if (lock == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    this.lock = lock;
}
```

Вот например кусок кода конструктора класса Reader. Правильно ли я понимаю, что он может использовать в качестве параметра любой обьект т.к. все обьекты в Java находтся в иерархии и наследуют от класса Object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, это так. Ваше предположение верно.

Так как все объекты в Java наследуют класс Object, они могут быть неявно преобразованы к нему. Значения элементарных типов будут вначале упакованы, а затем преобразованы к Object. Например: int -> Integer -> Object.

Таким образом, в вашем примере конструктор класса Reader сможет получить ровно один аргумент любого типа.